# Facebook ads for Android callback on ad click

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I use Facebook ads (via the latest FB SDK for Android) in my Android app.
Ads are working perfectly but there is one problem: customer whants to add additional tracking on ad clicks, so I need to get some callbacks when user clicks the ad.

Does anyone know how I can achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to ads within your app via FB's Audience Network? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network

Comment: @bjeavons Yes. I use NativeAd class to load and to display ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add AdListener object to NativeAd

   NativeAd.setAdListener(...)
2. Use onAdClicked method

   public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {...}